# WebAudioAPI: Trigger envelope based on input

Tags: javascript, signal-processing, web-audio-api

Context: I'm trying to make a 100% modular synthesizer on the web

So far, the tutorials I've seen for making envelopes used functions to trigger the different stages of the envelope, but what if I want to trigger an envelope based on the output of an AudioNode?

For example, attack on the rising edge of a square wave oscillator, and release on the falling edge?

Will I have to resort to using a script processor node (and suffer in performance) or is there a better way to do this that I haven't found out yet?

Thanks in advance

Clarification:

The input is a simple binary gate. 1 when the key is held down, 0 when it isn't.

There should be a few parameters that are AudioParams that will allow for control over attack time, decay time, sustain level and release time. It is assumed that the decay level (the peak of the ADSR envelope) is 1

The output is the ADSR envelope signal itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an alternative approach.  If you had analog circuitry, you could differentiate your square wave to get a positive impulse at the leading edge and a negative impulse at the trailing edge.  Feed this impulse train into an RC circuit.  This would produce an attack and release phase.

In WebAudio, you can do a simple differentiator by delaying the signal one sample and subtracting it from the original.  For the RC circuit, you can use a `BiquadFilterNode` or an `IIRFilterNode` to produce the desired result.

I'm not exactly sure what to do if you want a more complicated ADSR response.

Comment: what mechanism in the filter node would you use as a callback to tigger the asdr. In other words I think he's looking for some kind of event listener?

Comment: I guess we really need more information about exactly what the "other" signal looks like and what the use case really is.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! It works well in terms of getting the attack and release phases, but I ultimately would also want a decay phase. I shall use this method temporarily. Right now I'm experimenting with DynamicCompressor nodes and some signal gain and offset manipulation to see if I can get a full ADSR with conenctable audio params.

Comment: @bob Nope, I'm looking towards something like an ADSR output that will be connected directly to the gain AudioParam of the GainNode.

Comment: I would recommend pinging Andre Michelle, he's probably got a few tricks up his sleeve. He was, perhaps, the most influential flash-based audio developer and has been moving to web-audio since the fall of flash. http://www.andre-michelle.com/

Answer (score 1):

While I don't quite understand where/how the node used to trigger will actually trigger something (other than using the sourceNode.onended event, ultimately I believe you'll need to deal with the envelope using the setValueAtTime and linearRampToValueAtTime upon an attached gain node. Again, how you derive the time for the attack, sustain and release is still a mystery.

At any rate, this is a basic gist of how I'm building the envelope:

```
var triggerAtTime = 10;
var attackTime = 3;
var sustainTime = 5;
var releaseTime = 5;

var attackVol = 0.8;

var attackStartTime = triggerAtTime;
var attackEndTime = triggerAtTime + attackTime;

var releaseStartTime = attackEndTime + sustainTime;
var releaseEndTime = releaseStartTime + releaseTime;

var gainNode = ctx.createGain();
var gng = gainNode.gain;

gng.setValueAtTime(0, attackStartTime);
gng.linearRampToValueAtTime(attackVol, attackEndTime);

gng.setValueAtTime(attackVol, releaseStartTime);
gng.linearRampToValueAtTime(0, releaseEndTime);

sourceNode.connect(gainNode);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is what I already have, and what I'm actually looking for is how to trigger the setValueAtTime() & linearRampToValueAtTime() functions based on the output of another node. In this case, all the ADSR times have been hardcoded. But is there a way to trigger this envelope, say, based on another square wave oscillator, where the rising edge is treated as 'note on', and the falling edge as 'note off'?

Comment: If the other node is a square wave, you could implement this (at least partially) using a simple filter.  The input to the filter is the square wave and the output of the filter sets the gain of a gain node.  On the rising edge of the wave, the output of the filter will ramp up to 1.  On the trailing edge, the output of the filter ramps down to 0.  These ramps have a certain symmetry which you may not want.  then a more complicated scheme will be needed.